# AMP bind limit exceed

Tags: amp-html

I have developed an AMP project where I have created an amp-list pulling data from endpoint. Inside the amp-list it has 24 tiles and on each tile some numbers of operands to manage single item properties and features. I have also developed pagination to change page to page by changing amp-list through [src] change technique. It has more than 10k+ pages.

After browsing 5 or 6 more pages, 2000 bind limit exceed happen and site totally frozen. No bind related execution can not be done then.

Though I have a pagination more than 10k+ pages and each page have 24 items with identical operands so there always be a chance of exceed limit of 2000, which is now happening after browsing 5/6 pages consecutively.

How this situation can be resolved on AMP project now and limit exceed should not halt the process?

Answer (score 1):

This has been an on-going discussion on the AMP-HTML GitHub for quite some time. They have recently just begun increasing the number of allowed operands - it was 50 a few months ago. As recently as June 12th it was increased to 2000.

[Here is thread one](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/11434) where the operand discussion began. It has some good discussion on eliminating unnecessary variables to reduce your operand usage.

[Here is thread two](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/15980) which appears to have made the case to push the limit to 2000.

If you're unable to get your operand usage down by using some of the suggestions in thread one, you could certainly explain your use case in thread two for the AMP developers to look at.

Comment: Thanks @craig-scott for your suggestions. I have already looked at thread one and thread two. minimize operands as much as could not solve my issue, because my project has identical features and i have already minimized as much as i can. i have 10k+ pages, so 2000 limit may cross any time. So need to way out not to capture while limit exceed. I have already opened a new thread where i have explain my problems, [HERE IS THE NEW THREAD](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/17233).
On my new thread I added an idea on last part of the thread description tag name **Idea:**